# Is there a Ctrl + Tab equivalent on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to cycle trough the windows of the currently active application on Mac OS X. Some applications respond to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> but they all seem to do something else. I want to switch between the [Entourage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Entourage) mainscreen and the message I am writing for instance. Is there a such a keyword shortcut?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (the ~ key) works with many programs.

Comment: OK, so I have to ask, how do you get the key effect?

Comment: The HTML tag "KBD" is allowed.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed

Comment: This seems to work only in English keyboards ? I have a Japanese keyboard and the <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>｀</kbd> does nothing for me. I defined <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Keyboard & Text input > `Move focus to next window`

Comment: This doesn't do anything at all in Google Chrome for me.

Answer (score 8):

Depends on the application but most of them support:

- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

for switching between tabs.

Comment: this, but no Shift for me.

Comment: Without shift it goes back and forward in a browser.

Answer (score 5):

There is a piece of shareware [called Witch](http://www.manytricks.com/witch/) that emulates Windows <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>. It shows all windows in all applications, sorted by application. It costs €9.95.

Comment: Also Optimal Layout which is in the App Store

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your settings. Default settings depend on your locale.

See System Preferences -> Keyboard and Mouse -> Keyboard Shortcuts to see what the keys are on your system for e.g. "Move focus to next window in active application"

Answer (score 2):

Thought I'll consolidate the various responses for this:

1. To switch focus between windows in the current application, use CMD + ` combination (like multiple ppt files opened)
2. To switch between applications use CMD + TAB combination
3. To switch between tabs within an application (like Chrome), use CMD + Shift + [ (OR) CMD + Shift + ]

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>.
It switches focus between windows in the current application.
To switch between applications use <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Not quite the same as Windows' switching between all active windows, but close enough once you get used to the distinction.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>
For putting in tabs in table boxes to avoid jumping to the next column.

Comment: What do you mean "table boxes"?