# Most effective way when switching windows from different applications in OS X

Tags: macos, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switch between windows on mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/45310/switch-between-windows-on-mac)

What do you think is the most effective way when switching windows from different applications in Mac OS X, apart from exposé and CMD+TAB?

Comment: Depending on *what* you find effective, I guess it's answered at any of the following. [Switch between windows on mac?](http://superuser.com/questions/45310/), [Is there a ctrl+tab equivalent on Mac OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/276/), [How to switch back to previous window on OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/72547/), [How are you switching windows in OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/84552/), [Cycling through minimized windows](http://superuser.com/questions/26770/), ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight forward if you can't see both windows at the same time is to use Exposé (as <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> will bring all of the other application's windows to the front).

If you're looking for an alternative (my hunch is that this is what you're trying to ask), check out [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) - More similar to Windows' Alt-Tab.